# Another probability game

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Here is a contrived game, that there could be some benefit for solving. I hope it will turn out somehow like the Monty Hall problem.

A gameshow. First here is the simpler game. A contestant spins a spinner on a target.

[image]

Then the gameshow host spins the target, without looking at where the contestant's spinner wound up.

[image: spun target]

Then the host measures how far right and left the spinner is from the center, and draws a circle that width.

[image: circle added]

Finally, a blindfolded monkey throws darts in the general direction of the target until one of them does hit the target. If it hits the green circle, the contestant wins.

I think we can agree that this is basicly a fair game where the contestant has a one-half chance to win. The circle spinning gives them a random angle which gives a circle of random size, on average one half. The monkey is no more likely to hit the center of the target than an edge, so the chance to win is just the area of the circle divided by the area of the target.

Now here is the more interesting game. There are two contestants. They each spin an arrow randomly, at the same time so they don't have any idea where the other arrow will land. Then the host spins the target to randomize things more. Then they draw two circles. Then the blindfolded monkey throws the dart.

[image]

Both contestants win if the dart either lands inside *both* circles, or outside both circles.

A famous statistician argues that their chance to win ought to be one half, on average. The chance for each of them is one half. Their spins are independent.

But experience shows that they in fact win around 59% or 60% of the time.

How can that be?

Edit: In case it isn't obvious that the single-player game has probability 1/2:

The player has some angle after the host's spin, each angle is equally probable, so for the whole probability we would find the probability for a game with some angle $\theta$, and then integrate over $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$. (Cosines from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ should be the same.)

The probability of winning given some $\theta$ is $cos^2\theta$, because the circle with radius $\theta$ has area $\pi \cos^2\theta$ while the whole target has area $\pi$.

$$ \sideset{}{_0^{\pi}}\int \cos^2(\theta) d\theta = \frac{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + \theta}{2} = \frac{\cos(\pi)\sin(\pi) + \pi}{2}-\frac{\cos(0)\sin(0) + 0}{2}= \pi/2 $$

Since the domain is $[0,\pi]$ the average result is 1/2.

Comment: Can you explain accurately (more details) how the circle is drawn/calculated? What does it mean for the spinner to be some distance right or left of center?

Comment: @DavidP Basicly, the player's spinner has an angle theta. Calculate cos(theta). Draw the circle around the origin with radius theta. Its area will then be cos^2(theta) and if the surface area of the whole target is 1 unit, then the area that isn't inside the circle will be sin^2(theta).

Comment: @Tim, thank you for pointing out the issues. I wrote out a quick explanation of the probability 1/2 thing. I think there are important similarities between this game and an important physics problem. It's arguable how similar it is. This version might be easier to see the arguments against probability 1/2 than the other one.

Comment: You need to start with the way the spinner position dictates the diameter of the circles.  As it is we don't know why the spinner matters until the last few paragraphs.

Comment: I'm still confused about the construction of the circle. You say "draw the circle around the origin with radius there" but theta is an angle not a linear measurement, do you mean $\cos\theta$?

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused Oops! Yes, I meant cos $\theta$. I changed the picture hoping to make that clearer.